# On Button click, page should open in new tab -asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have popup, on click of which new popup opens and then when user fills the data, it redirects to page which also opens in a popup. I want that page to be open in new tab and the popup should get closed.

Please help how to achieve this using asp.net code behind
See my code for what I tried,

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "window.open('dummy.aspx')", "\", \"\");", true);  // tried with both, but not working
       Response.Redirect("dummy.aspx");
}
```

Can't use onClientClick as I have several other validation on the button click

Comment: `"I have popup, on click of which new popup opens and then when user fills the data, it redirects to page which also opens in a popup"` - Whoa.

Comment: "Please help how to achieve this" - my recommendation is "don't" - one popup is bad, multiple popups are a nightmare.

Comment: @David: Acutally, I have two popup one after the another.!

Comment: I want on the second popup there is a button. On click of that, a page opens. I want that page to be opened in new tab and also the form which I clicked the submit button should get refreshed.

Comment: You can do client side script like JQuery instead of script handling in server side.

Comment: can you explain me how to achieve that ? Please as it is urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a link to your html:

```
<a id="dummy" href="dummy.aspx" style="display:none;" target="_blank"></a>
```

Let's suppose you have a javascript function for refreshing a form:

```
function refresh() {
    //your code here
}
```

Then, let's suppose you have a function for opening the page in another tab and also refreshes your form:

```
function formHandler() {
    $("#dummy").click();
    refresh();
}
```

You need to call `formHandler` where you want to open the page in a new tab and refresh the form. This solution not always opens a new tab, in some browsers it opens a new window.

Comment: I already call the popup page here at:-
<a id="dummy" href="dummy.aspx" style="display:none;" target="_blank"></a>
and what code to write on refresh()

Comment: You need to write the code there which refreshes the form. I do not know anything from your form though.

Comment: Please see my js fiddle: After two popup on button click I want the page dummy.aspx to be opened in new tab. http://jsfiddle.net/93Lembaj/1/

Comment: actually, now it is working in Ff, but not in chrome, see my code:-
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", String.Format("window.open('{0}','_tab ')", ResolveUrl("dummy.aspx")), true);

Comment: You need to call the Javascript function using the ScriptManager. I mean the function which is responsible for the behavior you want to achieve. In your fiddle, fancybox is undefined. Also, can you specify how is it not working in Chrome, what do you experience?

Comment: In chrome it is opening as a new window, whereas It is working fine in  FF as new tab. Which ScriptManager will I need to use. can u help me with that.

Comment: I have described this in my answer. Previously I have been researching whether it is possible to force opening in new tabs and I concluded that there is no way to force opening in a new tab. Some browsers will open a new window and there is nothing you can do about it. If it is good-enough, then you have reached a solution. If you want to force them to open a tab, then there is no solution to your task.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me confirm with my senior. As I think your description is full proof.

Comment: one thing, after submit if I want to close the popup window, what is the code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63414/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-lajos-arpad).

Comment: I have entered the chat after some delay, sorry for making you waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Your controller Id ="Button1" then jquery code come like this

```
$("#Button1").click(function (){
window.open("url");
});
```

This jquery code will be handled in client side. so you will not have any issue in server side logic that you would like to perform validations.

Comment: for opening in new tab ? I think this will not work.

Comment: Go through it http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open